# How do I setup audio on arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, dwm

#### How can I install audio on arch linux?

If it helps any arch is on a usb, and my window manager is dwm.
I'm willing to give any output needed.

Answer (score 1):

Install these packages:

```
pulseaudio alsa-utils
```

For bluetooth:

```
pulseaudio-bluetooth bluez bluez-utils
```

As well as this program (execute it, to set one of your microphones as default):

```
pavucontrol
```

And this program for bluetooth (not needed, but I find it very useful):

```
blueman
```

Comment: Thanks this is the right answer!

Comment: @BruhImNotThatStupid It is preferred to accept the answer that worked for you by clicking the check mark instead of editing the title to include the word “SOLVED”.